# Configure uWSGI to continue logging both to default logger and to a custom logger

Tags: logging, configuration, uwsgi

I am attempting to create an error log file that is a filtered set of error logs. Using the config below all matching error logs are rerouted to this file and disappear from the default logger. Is there a way to duplicate error logs to another logger instead of rerouting them?

```
[uwsgi]
# Create a file logger named test
logger = test file:/tmp/uwsgi.log
# Format the logs specifically 
log-encoder = format:test format-this-right,${msgnl}
# Send only logs matching this regex to test
log-route = test curse the uwsgi instance .*
```